# Using a c++ function in an other c++ function (inside a R Package with Rcpp)

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I try to create a R package (using Rcpp).
Everything works fine. But now I wrote a c++ function, which I want to call in an other c++ file. 
So in */src* there is:

- function1 = linearInterpolation.cpp
- function2 = getSlope.cpp

Let's take function1, which just do a linear interpolation between two points at a specific position.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

//' @name linearInterpolation
//' @title linearInterpolation
//' @description Twodimensional linearinterpolation for a specific point
//' @param xCoordinates Two x coordinates
//' @param yCoordinates Coresponding two y coordinates
//' @param atPosition The Point to which the interpolation shall be done
//' @return Returns the linear interpolated y-value for the specific point
//' @examples
//' linearInterpolation(c(1,2),c(1,4),3)
//'
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double linearInterpolation(NumericVector xCoordinates, NumericVector yCoordinates, double atPosition) {

  // start + delta y / delta x_1 * delta x_2
  return yCoordinates[1] + getSlope(xCoordinates, yCoordinates) * (atPosition - xCoordinates[1]);

}
```

and the slope is calculated in a different function (file).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

//' @name getSlope
//' @title getSlope
//' @description Calculates the slopes between two points in 2Dimensions
//' @param xCoordinates Two x coordinates
//' @param yCoordinates Coresponding two y coordinates
//' @return Returns the slope
//' @examples
//' getSlope(c(1,2),c(1,4),3)
//'
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double getSlope(NumericVector xCoordinates, NumericVector yCoordinates) {
  return (yCoordinates[1] - yCoordinates[0]) / (xCoordinates[1] - xCoordinates[0]);
}
```

I do not have any deeper knowledge in Rcpp or c++. I read the Vignette and *Writing a package that uses Rcpp* I think I also read the right parts but I didn't get it.

Why is the **getSlope** function not "visible" in the other function - as they are both in the same package.
How can I use the getSlope in the other file?

Sorry but I am really stuck.

Thanks and best Regards

Nico

Comment: You have to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work) these two files. It would be easier to put them in the same file.

Comment: Please tell us the error message you are getting. It is insufficient to simply say "function not visible". What does 'visible' mean?

Comment: Hi Verena, I do not want to put them into the same file. I would end up in a big mess with multiple functions. But thanks I will read throuh your link.

Hi Aaron, sure, sorry. The error I get is:
_'getSlope' was not declared in this scope_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should make another file, a header file `.hpp`, and put this in it:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
double getSlope(NumericVector xCoordinates, NumericVector yCoordinates);
```

or, better still,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
double getSlope(Rcpp:: NumericVector xCoordinates, Rcpp:: NumericVector yCoordinates);
```

and put `#include"myheader.hpp"` at the top of both of your cpp files. This is in order to declare this function such that both cpp files can see it.

---

> ... as they are both in the same package

Just because two things are in the same *R* package, that does not mean they are in the same C++ *translation unit* (i.e. cpp file), and the *translation unit* is the important thing for two C++ functions to see each other. They must be in the same cpp file, or you must use a header file.

Comment: Ok, this changes something...
Now I get some more errors.
in the .hpp file: 
 - 2x Numeric Vector was not declared in this scope
 - exprpession list treated as compound expression in initializier
 - previous declaration of 'double getSLope'
in the getSlope.cpp:
 - double getSlope redeclared as different kind of symbol

Sorry, now I am completely lost...

Comment: I forget something, and I've now updated the answer. Your header file should also include `#include <Rcpp.h>` as its first lines. This is in order that the header file 'understands what `NumericVector` is. Also, `using namespace Rcpp;`